VBA : How to make copying and pasting from external worksheets faster?
I have written a VBA code in order to open a number of input files, copy their contents and paste them in other output files on specific sheets.
The code works fine but it is running slow (Around 1h30) Would you be able to provide tips on how to improve this piece of code ?
`For j = 2 To 5
    For i = 1 To 10
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Paths_Inputs_Total(i)
        Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Output_Paths(j)
    If InStr(1, Output_Tabs_Total(i), "AP") <> 0 Then
        Sheets(Output_Tabs_Total(i)).Range("A:BA").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    ElseIf InStr(1, Output_Tabs_Total(i), "Info MP") <> 0 Then
        Sheets(Output_Tabs_Total(i)).Range("D:BF").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Else
        Sheets(Output_Tabs_Total(i)).Range("C:BG").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i
Next j`

Thank you in advance !

Have you disabled ScreenUpdating? Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Yes I have disabled ScreenUpdating already

Do any of the sheet to be copied involve merge cells? If not, since you use PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _         :=False, Transpose:=False you should use arrays. Now, what Paths_Inputs_Total and Output_Paths arre? Anyhow, if you need to open a huge number of files, this take a lot of time...

Is there a typo in this line? Sheets(Output_Tabs_Total(i)²).Range("A:BA").PasteSpecial

The sheets do not involve merged cells, "Paths_Input_Totals" are list of the input files to be opened, and "Output_Paths" is a lit of output paths where the data is to be copied (in the tabs mentionned in "Output_tabs_total". Yes It was a typo indeed, thank you for pinpointing it !

You can try assigning values instead of copying:
Dim i As Long, j As Long, a As Long, b As Long
Dim data, adr As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For j = 2 To 5
    For i = 1 To 10
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Paths_Inputs_Total(i)
        data = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
        a = UBound(data): b = UBound(data, 2)
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Output_Paths(j)
        
        If InStr(1, Output_Tabs_Total(i), "AP") <> 0 Then
            adr = "A1"
        ElseIf InStr(1, Output_Tabs_Total(i), "Info MP") <> 0 Then
            adr = "D1"
        Else
            adr = "C1"
        End If
        Sheets(Output_Tabs_Total(i)).Range(adr).Resize(a, b).Value = data
        ActiveWorkbook.Save
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    Next i
Next j
Application.ScreenUpdating = True


Thank you very much ! This was helpful indeed ! I have updated the code and it runs now much faster :)
